# What is the best way to update boolean variable in this particular scenario?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class and a method named ValidateEverything(), where IsEverythingValid becomes true only when a or b or both of them are true. I was wondering about what would be the best way to break the foreach loop. Also, what would the best approach to update IsEverythingValid variable. Assume that first three if/else-if conditions are valid.

```
public class Validator
{
    public bool IsEverythingValid { get; private set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }

    public Validator()
    {
        IsEverythingValid = false;
        ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
    }

    public void ValidateEverything(ID Id)
    {
        var everyThing = SomeOtherClass.GetValues(Id);

        bool a = true;
        bool b = true;

        foreach (Something someThing in everyThing)
        {
            // a = some logic based on the value will be updated
            // b = some logic based on the value will be updated

            if (!a && !b)
                ErrorMessage = "A and B both are messed up";
            else if (!a && !someThing.aAllowed)
                ErrorMessage = "Only A is messed up";
            else if (!b && !someThing.bAllowed)
                ErrorMessage = "Only B is messed up";
            else
                IsEverythingValid = true;

            if(ErrorMessage.Length > 0)
                break;
        }

        if (a || b)
        {
            IsEverythingValid = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to "break the foreach loop"?

Comment: Are you looking to turn a or b `false` when `someThing` is messed up?

Comment: @Ixrec I need to break it as soon as something is wrong. I don't need to go further.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman yes

Comment: What is your criteria for "best?"  It looks like the code you wrote already does what you want.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am not happy with this one "else IsEverythingValid = true;". Also, I was thinking of only making the IsEverythingValid to true in only one place.

Comment: According to your last `if` statement, `IsEverythingValid = a || b;`  Which is wrong, of course; it should be `IsEverythingValid = a && b`.  If it were me doing it, I would declare `ValidateEverything()` as returning a `bool`, and then I would simply `return a && b`.

Comment: So 'IsEverythingValid' is "true only when a or b or both of them are true"? Does this mean that if a is true and b is false, then IsEverythingValid is true? If so, that's confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're doing a bunch of stuff yourself needlessly. You're also treating ranges as if they are values- for example you set one error message regardless of how many objects actually failed. A bit of LINQ will handle this easily for you.

Try

```
var failures = everyThing
               .Select(e => new { a = /* stuff */, b = /* stuff */ })
               .Where(obj => (!obj.a && !obj.aAllowed) || (!obj.b && !obj.bAllowed))
               .ToList();
IsEverythingValid = failures.Count == 0;
ErrorMessage = String.join("\n", failures.Select(obj => /* something */));
```

Comment: nitpick: could also use `!failures.Any()`, instead of Count, also ToList maybe unnecessary

Comment: I don't think `Filter` is a LINQ method. Do you mean `Where`? And yeah, `ToList` is not necessary. Although I don't think it's actually hurting performance in this case.

Comment: Oops, Where is indeed what I meant. As for the ToList, I only added it because I think that if you evaluate the `failures` twice you can cause multiple evaluations, which I figured is generally undesirable.

Comment: *[Converts newbie code to Linq, gets +1.](https://imgflip.com/readImage?iid=14310949)*

Comment: This looks great but in the current codebase(,which was developed few years back), we are not using LINQ statements too much.

Comment: That's a thing you can start fixing immediately. Also, they're expressions.

Comment: haha, I wish I could be such a pragmatic programmer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your testing to be:

```
public void ValidateEverything(ID Id)
{
  var everyThing = SomeOtherClass.GetValues(Id);

  bool a = true;
  bool b = true;

  foreach (Something someThing in everyThing)
  {
    if (someThing.thisIsBroke) 
    {
      a = false;
      break;
    }
    if (someThing.thatIsBroke) 
    {
      b = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  somethingIsValid = a || b;
  everythingIsValid = a && b;
}
```

The `break` statement will exit the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

> what would the best approach to update IsEverythingValid variable.

The way this is written you can simply remove the first setting of IsEverythingValid. See comments.

```
        foreach (Something someThing in everyThing)
        {
            if (!a && !b)
                ErrorMessage = "A and B both are messed up";
            else if (!a && !someThing.aAllowed)
                ErrorMessage = "Only A is messed up";
            else if (!b && !someThing.bAllowed)
                ErrorMessage = "Only B is messed up";
            else
                IsEverythingValid = true;  //<-Pointless, can't get here...
                //ab can get here
                //ff f
                //ft t
                //tf t
                //tt t

            if(ErrorMessage.Length > 0)
                break;
        }

        if (a || b)
        {
            IsEverythingValid = true;  //...without ending up here
            //ab can get here
            //ff f
            //ft t
            //tf t
            //tt t
        }
```

Which means, regardless of `everyThing` you're not validating anything but a and b.

> what would be the best way to break the foreach loop

Not this.

Consider what happens to your code and your error messages if you need to add a `c` that needs validating.  Think that's bad? Try to add a `d` as well.

Every line you now have to change is a place for bugs to sneak in.  I'd favor a design that was a little more tolerant of change.

I tend to leave validating code in the class that needs validating.  I don't create a Validator class.

What I do is have a validate method in the class that I call when the class should be valid.  This permit's me to use setters without worrying that the class could be left in a bad state because, say, not all setters were called before someone tried to use it.  I guard use of the class with a call to validate() before I allow anything to be done with the class besides calling the setters.

But, you seem to be doing something else.  Your ErrorMessage reporting is causing problems because you've only allowed for one error message.  You've twisted your logic in knots trying to accommodate the need to reflect your state with one message.

Consider this:

```
     public bool IsEverythingValid
     {
         get { return (ValidateEverything().Length == 0); }
     }

     public string ValidateEverything(ID Id)
     {
        ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
        var everyThing = SomeOtherClass.GetValues(Id);

        bool a = true;
        bool b = true;

        foreach (Something someThing in everyThing)
        {
            if (!a && !someThing.aAllowed)
                ErrorMessage += "A is messed up on " + someThing.name + Environment.NewLine;
            if (!b && !someThing.bAllowed)
                ErrorMessage += "B is messed up on " + someThing.name + Environment.NewLine;

            return ErrorMessage;
        }
     }
```

Now you're reporting state completely with your message.  Adding a `c` or a `d` wouldn't be difficult.  You aren't setting IsEverythingValid to a value and letting the world change around you without updating it before reporting it.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it didn't help me a lot. You know, it's hard to make understand the exact scenario without copying and pasting the exact same code.